# Where do I test the tutorial 3 of Datameer Developer Guide

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am working for the Datameer plugin development and I am struck at Tutorial 3 of it. Does anybody know where do I see that Freemarker widget that I build in tutorial 3 working in Datameer UI???

I don't have the permission to create new tags and hence putting it under Hadoop. If anybody has the appropriate privileges, please create one for `Datameer`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the tutorial was for Datameer v1.4. We introduced an entirely new data visualization module in v2.0 and we are working on providing the same customizability for it in a near future release.

Comment: I am ok with that. Can you just let me know where and how do I check that the plugin that I developed is working fine. I checked the logs and it says that the plugin got registered successfully. I don't know where to see it on the UI. Can you indicate where is that on the Datameer UI?

Comment: What kind of plugin did you write? For which version of Datameer? You should be able to find a list of loaded plugins in the Admin tab.

Comment: Let me check in the Admin tab. BTW, its the tutorial 3 on the SDK Documentation. Here is the [URL](http://www.datameer.com/documentation/display/DAS13/Tutorial03+-+Building+Custom+Widgets)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response on this post. It turns out that in version 2.0+ of Datameer the visualization (now called Infographics) module has been rewritten leveraging the power of HTML5 to more intuitively visualize your data analysis.

I recommend that you take a look at the new features that 2.0 has to offer under http://www.datameer.com/learn/videos.html.